# Silk Test tutorials

Tags: silktest

Can anyone help me?
Where can I find some websites with "Silk Test" tutorials?
I tried to find some on Google but I didn't find anything interesting.
Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are official tutorials on Micro Focus page: http://www.microfocus.com/education-services/web-based-training/#Silk. Although the page says that you have to purchase them, they are free of charge.